# image with webKit transform appeat under the next div

Tags: jquery, css, image, accordion

I trying to resolve this issue shown in the image for clarification.  I have a small thumbnail with webkit transform.  when I hover, The size get bigger.  Wehn I use accordion, part of the enlarged image appears under the accordion div.   I tried z-index, but it did not work.   I would greatly appreciate any idea on what tag attribute or jquery function that may help resolve.

thank you
Mike

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `z-index` property only affects elements that have a position value other than static (the default).
Try adding `position: relative` to the thumbnail element.

```
.smallImages {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```